# Angularjs not updating data inside $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code:

```
$scope.t = ["lapi", "laptop"];

$scope.$watch('search', function(newval, oldval){

$scope.alldata = [];

$http.get('http://localhost/serve/?p=12345').

    then(function(data){

        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2));

        $scope.alldata.push($scope.t[x])

    },

    function(){

        console.log("error")

    });

    return $scope.alldata;

});
```

every time it updating with previous result.

if i do $scope.$apply() after push ,

it is showing Error: [$rootScope:inprog]

I don't know how to update this data.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app="test">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sys.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="main">
    <p>Angularjs Test</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" typeahead="data for data in alldata | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10"autofocus>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
var app=angular.module('test', ["ui.bootstrap"]);

app.controller("main", function($scope, $http, $timeout, $q){
    console.log("main");
    var timer = false;
    $scope.search = "";
    $scope.t = ["vijay", "vijaypal"];
    $scope.alldata = [];
    $scope.getLog = function(){
        console.log("rootscope called");
    };
    $scope.$watch('search', function(newval, oldval){
        
        if(timer) {
            $timeout.cancel(timer);
        }
        timer = $timeout(function(){
            $scope.alldata = [];
            var rd='&_rd='+new Date().getTime();
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get("http://rec.cloudinfra.in/rec_serve_property/?p=3903405"+rd).
            then( function(data) {
                var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2));
                    $scope.alldata.push($scope.t[x]);
                    deferred.resolve($scope.alldata)
                    console.log("start:", $scope.alldata);
                    return deferred.promise;
            },
            function (){
                console.log("error");
            });
        }, 100);
        console.log("end:", $scope.alldata);
        
    });
});
```

check in console log you will get the problem

Comment: Sounds like a caching problem. Append a random parameter to the query and try again.

Comment: forget about query; not able to do $scope.$apply inside $http.get that is already inside $watch

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are even trying to do.  You use `$http.get()` to fetch some data, and when the promise completes, you aren't even using the data, and are instead trying to push some random numbers?

Comment: you can't use `$scope.$apply` inside the `$http.get()` (and don't really need to), since it's already in the middle of a digest cycle.  your data isn't updating for some other reason, the digest (`$scope.$apply`) wouldn't fix it even if you could run it.

Comment: not updating data even i am appending some random number

Comment: @VijayKumar Is your code inside a controller or service. I suspect that, it is because of asynchronous call which is not returning a promise during the watch cycle. This $http returns the data asynchronously, after your $watch cycle, You can verify this behavior by giving console.log(). Try to use $q.defer service to return the promise .... Reference plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/tIiMDWeyVfaofABHnQ0w?p=preview

Comment: not solve the problem

Comment: @VijayKumar Can you please, paste your complete code or create plunker link for the same. It would enable us to debug

Comment: thanks ; i will paste complete code

Comment: @Hurix  , I pasted full code , can u check please?

Answer (score 0):

looks like cache issue and try to change the request to

```
var rd='&_rd='+new Date().getTime();

$http.get('http://localhost/serve/?p=12345'+rd)
```

so you can have different request everytime

Comment: request is not successfully completing , it is going inside error.

Comment: when you say updating, what exactly is going to be update? the response from server? if yes, can you describe or post the code of server side method so we can be sure that there is nothing wrong in server side

Comment: its giving same result as previous

Comment: Actually i m building autocomplete feature;  in every keystroke i m sending typed keys to server and getting result and showing as autocomplete; but it is showing previous result every time.

Comment: @VijayKumar in that case, you may want to check the following things as well: 1. typed keys is captured properly and sent to server, 2. your sever side method work properly with different captured keys

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is **$http.get().success(function(){}).error(function(){});** as far as I am aware of.

```
$scope.t = ["lapi", "laptop"];

$scope.$watch('search', function(newval, oldval){

$scope.alldata = [];

$http.get('http://localhost/serve/?p=12345').success(function($data) {
   //$data is the data stripped from the response! unlike XMLHttpRequest
   var x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2) - 1; //This wasn't an integer
   $scope.alldata.push($scope.t[x]);
   //no need to return
}).error(function() {
   console.log('error');
});
```

Comment: Well, there is nothing wrong with the syntax. Can you show me your request and response of statuscodes of ''http://localhost/serve/?p=12345'' ? Furthermore, when I read your code, I believe you're trying to add a random element to your alldata, regardless of the response?